# When does Deathfire Grasp calculate?

Tags: league-of-legends

When is the amount of damage that Deathfire Grasp does calculated? Is it when it is casted/used or is it when the missile hits the target? If I do damge to the person before it reaches them, will the damage of DFG change?

Answer (score 1):

As with all missile effects, it triggers when it hits the champion. This means that it will deal damage based on the HP of the target when it hits them. This is why it is important to start your combo of spells with Deathfire Grasp in order to maximize its damage dealt.

Answer (score 0):

If you do damage to the target before it hits them it will calculate then. it is at the time that it hits the target, so lead in with it, then follow up.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to say when the missile hit the target because that is when the damage is dealt. It's done this way in case the target uses a spell shield to cancel the effect.